# How to copy Eigen matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have two `Eigen::MatrixXd` and they always have a single row. The input matrix is `A` and I want to copy this matrix into another matrix `B`, but the number of columns between the matrices can be different.

Following is an example:

```
A
 0.5
```

And I need to create a `B` matrix of 1 rows and 4 columns, so that it will be:

```
B
 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
```

But if `A` is:

```
A
 1 0.5
```

Then `B` will be

```
B
 1 0.5 1 0.5
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can replicate a matrix by using the (wait for it) `replicate` function. The first parameter is how many times to repeat the rows, the second is the number of times to repeat the columns.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd a(1, 2), b;
    a << 1, 0.5;
    b = a.replicate(1, 2);
    std::cout << a << "\nbecomes:\n" << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

gives

> 1 0.5
>   becomes:
>     1 0.5   1 0.5