# What is the Eigen equivalent of Matlab repelem?

Tags: matlab, eigen

In Matlab, there is both [repmat](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [repelem](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html). For matrices `x1` and `x2` of sizes `[d, n1]` and `[d, n2]`, you can do this in Matlab:

```matlab
n1 = size(x1, 2);
n2 = size(x2, 2);

M = repmat(x1, 1, n2) - repelem(x2, 1, n1);
```

What is the equivalent Eigen code? Below are four variants that I am not quite satisfied with. I wonder if it could be made into a faster one-liner?

TL;DR: Variant 2 is best, but it depends on the compiler and other things.

```cpp
int d = x1.rows();
int n1 = x1.cols();
int n2 = x2.cols();

Eigen::MatrixXd M(d, n1*n2);

// Variant 1:
int idx = 0;
for (int c = 0; c != n2; c++) {
  for (int r = 0; r != n1; r++) {
    M.col(idx) = x1.col(r) - x2.col(c);
    idx += 1;
  }
}

// Variant 2:
for (int c = 0, idx = 0; c != n2; c += 1, idx += n1)
  M.block(0, idx, d, n1) = x1.colwise() - x2.col(c);

// Variant 3:
M = - x2.replicate(n1, 1);
M.resize(d, n1*n2);
M += x1.replicate(1, n2);

// Variant 5:
M = x1.rowwise().replicate(n2) - x2(all,VectorXi::LinSpaced(n1*n2,0,n2-1));
```

Here are my current timings, see below for the complete code. Matlab timings are for multithread and single thread Matlab R2017b. C++ versions compiled with flags `-O3 -DNDEBUG -march=native -mtune=native`. All were run on a `i5-6500`, so I have `AVX`.

```
               time in seconds
Code         gcc-7  gcc-8 clang-6
-----------------------------------
Matlab mt  51
Matlab st  84
V. 1           38    37     57
V. 2           36    34     23
V. 3          598   599    187
V. 5           94   172    107
```

Matlab code:

```matlab
ds = 1:10;
n1s = 5:5:500;
n2s = 5:5:500;

z1 = randn(max(ds), max(n1s));
z2 = randn(max(ds), max(n2s));

tic;
s = 0;
for idx = 1:numel(ds)
    for jdx = 1:numel(n1s)
        for kdx = 1:numel(n2s)
            K = MFdiff(z1(1:ds(idx), 1:n1s(jdx)),...
                z2(1:ds(idx), 1:n2s(kdx)));
            s = s + K(1,1);
        end
    end
end
toc
```

C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

template <typename Derived1, typename Derived2>
MatrixXd MFdiff1(
  DenseBase<Derived1> const & x1,
  DenseBase<Derived2> const & x2)
{
  int d = x1.rows();
  int n1 = x1.cols();
  int n2 = x2.cols();

  MatrixXd out(d, n1*n2);

  int idx = 0;
  for (int c = 0; c != n2; c++) {
    for (int r = 0; r != n1; r++) {
      out.col(idx) = x1.col(r) - x2.col(c);
      idx += 1;
    }
  }

  return out;
}

template <typename Derived1, typename Derived2>
MatrixXd MFdiff2(
  DenseBase<Derived1> const & x1,
  DenseBase<Derived2> const & x2)
{
  int d = x1.rows();
  int n1 = x1.cols();
  int n2 = x2.cols();

  MatrixXd out(d, n1*n2);

  for (int c = 0, idx = 0; c != n2; c+=1, idx += n1)
    out.block(0, idx, d, n1) = x1.colwise() - x2.col(c);

  return out;
}

template <typename Derived1, typename Derived2>
MatrixXd MFdiff3(
  DenseBase<Derived1> const & x1,
  DenseBase<Derived2> const & x2)
{
  int d = x1.rows();
  int n1 = x1.cols();
  int n2 = x2.cols();

  MatrixXd out;
  out = - x2.replicate(n1, 1);
  out.resize(d, n1*n2);
  out += x1.replicate(1, n2);

  return out;
}

template <typename Derived1, typename Derived2>
MatrixXd MFdiff5(
  DenseBase<Derived1> const & x1,
  DenseBase<Derived2> const & x2)
{
  int n1 = x1.cols();
  int n2 = x2.cols();

  return x1.rowwise().replicate(n2) - x2(all,VectorXi::LinSpaced(n1*n2,0,n2-1));
}

double test(VectorXi const & ds,
      VectorXi const & n1s,
      VectorXi const & n2s)
{
  MatrixXd z1 = MatrixXd::Random(ds.maxCoeff(), n1s.maxCoeff());
  MatrixXd z2 = MatrixXd::Random(ds.maxCoeff(), n2s.maxCoeff());

  double s = 0;
  for (int idx = 0; idx!=ds.rows(); idx++) {
    for (int jdx = 0; jdx!=n1s.rows(); jdx++) {
      for (int kdx = 0; kdx!=n2s.rows(); kdx++) {
        MatrixXd K = MFdiff5(z1.block(0, 0, ds(idx), n1s(jdx)),
                 z2.block(0, 0, ds(idx), n2s(kdx)));
        s += K(0,0);
      }
    }
  }

  return s;
}  

int main() {
  VectorXi ds = VectorXi::LinSpaced(10, 1, 10);
  VectorXi n1s = VectorXi::LinSpaced(100, 5, 500);
  VectorXi n2s = VectorXi::LinSpaced(100, 5, 500);

  std::cout << test(ds, n1s, n2s) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417836/assigning-a-vector-to-a-matrix-column-in-eigen) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33808561/2899559) answer your question?

Comment: @AviGinsburg No, but the second question inspired variant 3 above, which is in fact slower.

Comment: Can you post the timings and full set of compiler flags? Also, what sizes are you talking about? And try the Eigen version as something like `M = x1.replicate(1, n2) - x2.replicate(n1, 1);`. The resize in the middle is just going to ruin performance.

Comment: @AviGinsburg The statement `M = x1.replicate(1, n2) - x2.replicate(n1, 1);` is only slightly faster than V3 above, but it does not compute the right thing! (try it!) My compiler flags are `g++-8 -std=c++1z -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3 -march=native -mtune=native` but the intended question was more of the algorithmic kind.

Comment: The size are as follows: `d` is in the range 1-10 and `n1'` and `n2`are in the range 1-1000.

Answer (score 4):

With the head of Eigen you can write:

```
M = x1.rowwise().replicate(n2) - x2(Eigen::all,VectorXi::LinSpaced(n1*n2,0,n2-1));
```

with same speed as your variant 2.

Self-contained benchmark (`BenchTimer.h` needs a clone of the repo), tested with `-O3 -DNDEBUG` with gcc 7 and clang 6:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <bench/BenchTimer.h>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

EIGEN_DONT_INLINE
void foo1(const MatrixXd& x1, const MatrixXd& x2, MatrixXd& M)
{
  int d = x1.rows();
  int n1 = x1.cols();
  int n2 = x2.cols();

  int idx = 0;
  for (int c = 0; c != n2; c++) {
    M.block(0, idx, d, n1) = x1.colwise() - x2.col(c);
    idx += n1;
  }
}

EIGEN_DONT_INLINE
void foo2(const MatrixXd& x1, const MatrixXd& x2, MatrixXd& M)
{
  int n1 = x1.cols();
  int n2 = x2.cols();

  M = x1.rowwise().replicate(n2) - x2(all,VectorXi::LinSpaced(n1*n2,0,n2-1));
}

int main()
{
  int tries = 2;
  int rep = 1;

  int d = 100;
  int n1 = 100;
  int n2 = 100;

  MatrixXd x1(d,n1); x1.setRandom();
  MatrixXd x2(d,n2); x2.setRandom();
  MatrixXd M(d, n1*n2);

  BenchTimer t;
  BENCH(t, tries, rep, foo1(x1, x2, M));
  std::cout << "Time: " << t.best() << "s" << std::endl;

  BENCH(t, tries, rep, foo2(x1, x2, M));
  std::cout << "Time: " << t.best() << "s" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: From the horse's mouth. Oddly enough, when I run this, it is a lot slower that v.2. I will have to make a robust benchmark and then return to this question.

Comment: I added this as variant 5 in my question. It is much slower in my benchmark. I also ran your code on my machine and got this: Time: 0.00131418s Time: 0.0111729s

Comment: hm... on a 2.6GHz Haswell, with clang 6 and `-O3 -DNDEBUG`, I get= `Time: 0.000690089s Time: 0.000568082s`. gcc 5, 6, or 7 give me similar results.

Comment: Yes, the times I reported earlier were an anomaly, running it many times I see about 1:1 on clang 6, 1:1,5 on gcc 7 and 1:8 on gcc 8 (in favour of v. 2). Seems to be compiler dependent. See my benchmark in the question.

Comment: I see that in your benchmark d is very small, between 1 and 10. In this case I agree that v2 is much faster.

Comment: More precisely, with a small `d`, you pay for the costly integer modulo and division in `replicate` and `LinSpaced`. There is not much we can do.